# Facebook Link Image

Tags: html, css, facebook

I recently designed and built this site: http://velvetbus.co.uk

When one of the administrators go to post a link on Facebook the post appears like this:

[image]

How can I change the icon? A 'v' is nice and all but doesn't really represent the company too well.

Thanks

Comment: You really have not explained very much! No code, no mention of your goal, etc...

Comment: Yes I have. The goal is to change the icon. There should be no code for me to say, the fact is I am unsure of the code to use to change the image.

Comment: Are you using facebook api? You haven't even mentioned an API of any sort. We need some more info if possible! Thanks :)

Comment: i have no idea if you can fix this on Facebook side. the problem is the image itself has a transparent background, Facebook get the image only not its parent, you need to add a background to the image itself not with css.

Comment: @pattyd No, if I were using the facebook API I would have mentioned it. This is a simple post to facebook via sharing a link :p

Comment: @Wahtever Thanks, that's a good shout. I'll give it a go!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding @jskidd3! I will help if possible! :)

Comment: @Wahtever Ah, no you seem to have misinterpreted the question. I don't mind about the image itself, transparent or not. I need to change the image altogether, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook uses Open Graph protocol. You need to add a meta tag on your web page so facebook will know what image do display

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://LINK_TO_YOUR_IMAGE"/>`

> It's best to use a square image, as Facebook displays them in that matter.
>       That image should be at least 50x50 in any of the usually supported image forms 
>       (JPG, PNG, etc.)

Here you can learn about other tags http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: Thanks so much! Will select as best answer as soon as the timer is up! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the facebook link from your website? Make sure to include a `<meta property="og:image" content="someimg.jpg" />` in the head of the url you're pointing to in your post, to tell Facebook which image to use for the post.

Jeroen